# Where can I find detailed information about a resolved issue in Toplink?

Tags: oracle, toplink, bug-tracking

I'm facing a very complicated problem in my application that is solved when I update from toplink 10.1.3 to toplink 10.1.3.4. Now I must find out which resolved issue (list available here http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/ias/toplink/doc/10131/relnotes/rel_notes.htm#BABBHCAA) is responsible for the solution, so I can convince the customer to update their toplink version.

I found an issue that is probably the one I need; its number is 6671556. But the list only shows a summary, a simplified description of the problem. Where can I find the detailed information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This detailed sort of information is kept in Oracle's Support Knowledge Base : the [Website Formerly Known As Metalink](https://support.oracle.com/CSP/ui/flash.html).  If you search on 6671556 you will find the bug note you want, "INVALID OBJECTS IN CACHE SHOULD BE REFRESHED WHEN REGISTERED IN UOW".

**edit**

Just to be clear, the ToR of the Support site forbid the public copying of this information.  So, if you don't have a Support contract you're probably out of luck.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to access this site before, but I couldn't. I just thought this kind of information was public.

Comment: Oracle make a lot of money from support. That's money they wouldn't make if they gave away "this kind of information".